# Why doesn't phonegap scale html5?

Tags: html, cordova

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, 
initial-scale=0.5, width=610, height=1024" />
```

The mobile is small,so I wan't to scale html5 to 0.5.It takes no effect via phonegap,but it's OK via chrome on iphone 5.
Is it phonegap's bug?

--------------Edit----------------

I found that if I move off the code I showed above,the chrome will still do well on scaling.The pictures are showed smaller than desktop views.It's scaled by default.

But phonegap doesn't.
How to make phonegap scale my html5?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```